# Editext (Dialog) Value is empty?

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

I try to use a `EditText` in a `Dialog`. I use the sample from developer.android.com (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). Now i want to get the `Value` of the EditText when i press the `positive Button`. 
My Code

```
    public Dialog onCreateDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(main_list.this);
    // Get the layout inflater
   final LayoutInflater inflater = main_list.this.getLayoutInflater();


    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.serie_add, null))
            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.search, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    View promptsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.serie_add, null);
                    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                            .findViewById(R.id.series);

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(main_list.this, add_series.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", userInput.getText());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code as:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog() {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(main_list.this);
// Get the layout inflater
final LayoutInflater inflater = main_list.this.getLayoutInflater();

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.serie_add, null);
final EditText userInput = (EditText) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.series);

builder.setView(view)
        // Add action buttons
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.search, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                View promptsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.serie_add, null);


                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(main_list.this, add_series.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", userInput.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        });
return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: The value is still empty ... :(

Comment: Check my edited code. I set userInput before the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you have two problems in the code.
The first one is that you are inflating the view during the onClick so obviously it is empty.
The inflation should be done prior and only then you should register on the onClick event.
Second, you're doing:

```
userInput.getText() instead of
userInput.getText().toString();
```